# Apache: setting up access permission not working

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I'm on Mac OS X and having problem in setting Apache to function properly. When I access localhost it keeps showing `403 forbidden You don't have permission to access this page` error. Though I have set Apache to gain access permission on Document Root (AFAK by googling). This is my setting in `httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">

Options All
AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is there something I misunderstood here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check file permissions for the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder. The `www` user should have at least read and execute permissions on the folders and read permissions on the files. Repair privileges if needed.

My settings (OS X 10.8, working webserver) are:

```
$ ls -la /Library/WebServer/Documents/
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel    170 10 Dic 04:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel    170 10 Dic 04:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3726 10 Dic 04:03 PoweredByMacOSX.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  31958 10 Dic 04:03 PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     44 12 Mar 17:48 index.html.en
```

Don't forget to check Apache logs into `/var/log/apache2/` (you can read them using the built-in Console application).